# How can I encrypt and decrypt data on client in Meteor React?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, encryption, meteor, meteor-react

I'm currently working on a password managing application in Meteor React and can't seem to find a way to encrypt and decrypt data on the client, with MmongoDB storing the encrypted data.

To add a little background to the task and specify what I am trying to do:
This whole application is for one single company and users are the employees only. The passwords, along with username info and some other attributes are stored in folders and users get view and edit rights to data within the folder. Passwords (along with additional info) need to be encrypted, but multiple users need to be able to access them based on the rights given to them. So when the data is encrypted, say when a person creates a password, other users with the rights to do so need to be able to decrypt this data as well. However, the decryption needs to happen on client and the server can only ever access the encrypted data.

I have tried using [planifica:encryption](https://github.com/Planifica/encryption), because it has exactly what we need for our project, but I ran into some errors and I can't get past them nor find any article about them. I have heard of [Mylar](https://css.csail.mit.edu/mylar/) in some answers to similar questions, but both Mylar and Planifica don't seem to have been updated for a few years now. I know Node.js has a crypto module, but I am not sure whether it could be used to share encrypted data among users and most importantly, how to do so.

Is there any way to do what we need for this project? I should also point out that I am relatively new to meteor and I have not dealt with encryption whatsoever, so my understanding is rather limited.

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This very much depends on the encryption you are using, but since you are interested in decrypting things client-side, it sounds like what you are looking for is the [SubtleCrypto web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt).

That should be all you need on top of what Meteor already provides. You should be able to use a regular meteor collection and publication to share the encrypted data with your clients, and then let them decrypt it using the above linked decrypt function. One question I'd have is how you will be able to get the decryption key to your clients while hiding it from the server, but I assume you've got that part figured out somehow.

Comment: Thank you so much for help. I tried it a little on a demo project today and so far it seems rather promising. The distribution of the decryption key will not be handled by the app at all, so it is not a problem. Again, thank you very much for your time